# How to make intellisense work with NANT Files in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, intellisense, nant

I started with an Empty Project, and tried to get my build file setup with

Here's what I have tried so far:

1. Found out what version of NAnt I'm using by running NAnt with the **-help** option.
2. In the following string replaced the version of NAnt I'm using in the following URL:

   - **http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/<my NAnt version>/nant.xsd**
   - In this example, lets say it's **0.90**.
3. Downloaded the file: from the above URL to **%VS_HOME%\Common7\Packages\schemas\xml**

   - **http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.90/nant.xsd**
4. Opened my buildfile in VS (from instide my solution and project)
5. From the menu clicked **XML->Schemas...** to add add the nant.xsd I downloaded earlier to the IDE.
6. After adding the schema made sure that it had a green checkmark next to it in the **Use** column of the **XML Schemas** window.
7. Added the following attribute in the <project> element of my build file:

   - **<project ... xmlns="http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.90/nant.xsd" >**
8. Clicked **OK** on **XML Schemas** window.
9. Lastly, I reopened my buildfile with the **open with...** the **XML Editor**.

After performing the above procedure in the **Error List** I get a list in the  **messages** section but I don't get any intellisense suggestions when typing (other than the defaults for XML, like !--, ![CDATA[, and ?)

Is there something else I need to change to make this work in VS2008?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added the `nant.xsd` file that ships with the version I have (0.85) to the schemas set in VS and then added this to my build file:

```
<project xmlns="http://nant.sf.net/release/0.85/nant.xsd" name="foo">
```

And it worked fine. Are you sure the XML namespace you're declaring for the 0.90 release is correct? Maybe it's **sf.net** rather than sourceforge.net.

Comment: I think the problem was that I had nant.sourceforge.net instead of nant.sf.net  As soon as I changed that it appeared to work!  Thanks man! :)  Also I didn't have to change it in the XML->Schemas... menu, to get it to work, I only changed it in my build file.  (When I went to check the settings in the XML->Schemas... menu the domain name had already changed).

Comment: Which is interesting because the `targetNamespace` attribute in the schema is declared as **http://nant.sf.net/release/0.85/nant.xsd**. Go figure :)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [nantschema task](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85/help/tasks/nantschema.html). You can get nant to puke out its own XML schema which will include any third-party extensions (nantcontrib, custom tasks, etc).

I have setup a website on my dev machine called nant.myprojectname.com (where myprojectname is replaced by whatever I want to call my project) and I get nant to copy the schema xsd file there as part of the build process. I just put nant.myproject.com into the local hosts file to get it to resolve on the local dev machine - I don't really need the schema available elsewhere.

I then put the following into the nant project element :

```
<project
    xmlns="http://www.myprojectname.com/myprojectnamenant"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="www.myprojectname.com/myprojectnamenant http://nant.myprojectname.com/myprojectnamenant.xsd"
    default="go"
    name="myprojectname">
```

The schemaLocation attribute tells Visual Studio (or whatever) to look at http://nant.myprojectname.com/myprojectnamenant.xsd for the schema. May need to reload VS before Intellisense kicks in.

Comment: Woo! Thanks for that! That sounds very useful!

Comment: Ah okay so you can have a global configuration property that'll just point to it then after it's been generated for whichever project you're in, incase something like vs needs it.

Comment: @leeand00 I've updated my answer with more details regarding what I do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to this question, but I was searching for the solution to this problem *with the twist of wanting intellisense for **NAntContrib** as well*. To do this follow these steps:

**Step 1:** You need to create a build script for the new `nant.sxd`, let's call this file `nantxsd.build` that includes the NAntContrib tasks:

```
<project name="nant" default="go">
    <property name="NAntContrib" value="E:\NAnt\nantcontrib-0.91-bin\nantcontrib-0.91\bin" />
    <target name="go">
        <loadtasks assembly="${NAntContrib}\NAnt.Contrib.Tasks.dll" />
        <nantschema output="nant.xsd" target-ns="http://nant.sf.net/release/0.91/nant.xsd"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

**Step 2:** Then build the new `nant.xsd` file from the command line. If you have installed NAnt you should be able to open the command line window in the same directory as the `nanntxsd.build` script and run:

> nant /f:nantxsd.build

**Step 3:** Copy the new nant.xsd to the Visual Studio XML\Schemas folder. For example:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Xml\Schemas\nant.xsd"